# Regex matching javadoc comment for a specific method (python)

Tags: python, regex, javadoc

I'm having trouble coming up with a regex that will match the javadoc comment contents for a specific java method. Example:

```
/**
 * Do not match this.
 */

/**
 * Do match this.
 */
@SomeAnnotation
public boolean methodX() { }
/**
 * Do not match this.
 */
```

I already know the method signature so I can use that in the regex.

I can match all of the javadoc comments using:

```
/\*\*(.*?)\*/
```

I'm also specifying re.DOTALL. I tried expanding the regex to use a negative lookahead that says I only want a javadoc comment if it's the comment immediately proceeding the method:

```
/\*\*(.*?)\*/(?!.*?/\*\*.*?public boolean methodX\(\))
```

But that's causing the (.*?) to match the contents from the start of the first javadoc comment to the end of the javadoc comment immediately proceeding methodX.

I keep trying various ways of constructing positive and negative lookaheads but nothing is working. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you looking to capture the annotation as well?  And are you trying to capture and use the text portion of the comment that you match?

Comment: I just need the text portion of the comment, but I can strip the *'s and extra newlines as a post-processing step. The text is fairly structured so I'm not too worried about weird edge cases. Most of the methods have several annotations so I just wanted to make sure that was communicated in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches the comment (from `/**` to `*/`) preceding the function in the given example text in a `comment` named group:

```
(?P<comment>/\*\*(?:(?!/\*\*).)*?\*/)(?:(?:(?!\*/).)*?)(?=public boolean methodX)
```

See a [test at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/bN3eK6/1).

- The key here is to ignore the extra `/**` and `*/` in the wanted text using `(?!/\*\*).)*?` and `(?!\*/).)*?`
- `?:`s are to scrape the uninteresting groups from the result

Comment: This has some odd behavior during a fringe situation: where an annotation might contain */.  This regex grabs the entire annotation up to that point as a part of the comment, when it should not.

Comment: @wolffer-east I see, how does such annotation look like? Could you provide an example please?

Comment: The following would have '@SomeAnnotation that contains ' as part of the comment capture: @SomeAnnotation that contains */ is a troublesome annotation.  If you follow the link in famousgarkin's post and add */ to the end of the annotation you will see the capture change.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is greedy and is currently matching the `*/` in the first comment (because `.*` matches `*/`). try using

```
/\*\*((?:[^*]+|\*[^/])*)\*/
```

This ensures that you will never match the ending `*/` by accident and end up with two comments matched at the same time

EDIT:
This code avoids the issue of annotations that contain */. not sure why they would, but here goes:

```
/\*\*((?:(?!\*/).)*)\*/(?:(?!/\*\*).)*(?=public boolean methodX)
```

check out this example for confirmation that it works: http://regex101.com/r/yV9oK2/2
I switched from my original match to a negative lookahead to avoid a 'catastrophic backtrack' as the test program put it :)